# symbol/ how to split into two separate numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi everyone so i'm solving the problem i have a script

this is the result from the web

```
1/5
```

how to split into two separate numbers?

the output is this how to do not let go if the number is greater than 5?

these are different numbers, for example:

```
1/4 
2/4
```

They need that the second numbers
is not greater than 5

```
let maxPopulation = document.querySelector("#content_value > table:nth-child(2) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(5)").innerText
```

normal code would be done like this

but the sign prevents me from doing that

```
if ((maxPopulation)> = 5)
```

the problem, however, makes me a sign / I don't know how to separate the two numbers and if the second one is bigger than 5 so that the script doesn't continue to work

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but to separate a string by a character use split: `"1/5".split('/')`. This will give you an array: `[ '1', '5' ]`

Comment: you can use toString().split('/'). Please try to do.

Comment: _“I don't know how to […]”_ - well then do a bit of _research_, please. There is no reason to assume that you were the first person ever in the history of the world, that had to solve such a trivial “problem”. Please show a _bit_ of effort at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use split function:

```
result = '1/5';
let splitted = result.split('/');
if(splitted[1]>=5)
   DoSomething();
```

split returns an array, so second part is at position [1]

**Update 1:**

According to your comments you need specifically this:

```
const fieldValues = document.querySelector("#content_value > table:nth-child(2) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(5)").innerText

const splitted = fieldValues.split('/');

if(parseInt(splitted[1])>=5){
   // your code for equal or greater than 5
}
else{
   // your code for < 5
}
```

Comment: how to apply it to this element?

I tried here but it didn't work here        let result= document.querySelector("#content_value > table:nth-child(2) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(5)").innerText

Comment: I think you should assign an id for each element that you want to be selectable. It will be much more easy to get the values. But for now you can try output innerText in console to see if its working, if not, its because the path for the element is wrong.

Comment: let result = document.querySelector("#content_value > table:nth-child(2) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(5)").innerText
let splitted = result.split('/');

console.log(splitted) this code give me aray 1 (4) and 2 (4)

Comment: if they use your code how is it that the show is doing something when the code should stop?

Comment: Please update your question with that html table you want to select and I can help more. Without details is hard to help.

Comment: Array 0 and 1 console log [
    "29",
    "29"
]   is aray 0 and 1 how can i put the data in the browser to calculate?    type innerText            const maxPopulation = document.getElementById("pop_max_label").innerText;
const currentPopulation = document.getElementById("pop_current_label").innerText;


// if ((maxPopulation - currentPopulation) >= 100) this type calculation

Comment: @JohnDeatd your question is confused for me. Please, do what I said, edit your question with the relevant parts html and javascript code. And let us know what you really want to do, because before you asked about split a string and know it seems to be a calc between two fields. Please give further details by updating your question and I will help you.

Comment: Please, go to your browser console, execute this ```console.log(document.querySelector("#content_value > table:nth-child(2) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(5)").innerText)``` and let me know what is being returned.

Comment: 0/4 return this code  i need to work just with aray (specifically calculate and if it will
second number greater than 5 so that the script does not start (or continue work)   the second number must not exceed 5

(before that there is a click function) I want to implement this into a mess I don't know how to count the two numbers)

Comment: @JohnDeatd I just updated my answer, see that.

Comment: @JohnDeatd if it helps you please mark this answer as correct. It will help other people in future.

Answer (score 0):

you can use split method

```
let result="1/5".split('/');
console.log(result)    //['1','5']
```